# How do I generalize the transfer of data between processors to a number of processors greater than 2?

Tags: mpi

I need to transfer the left most rij columns of an array (slast) from my_rank to my_rank-1 (paddedSright) and the rightmost rij columns of an array (slast) to my_rank+1 (paddedSleft). On my_rank equal zero just the rightmost RIJ columns are transferred to my_rank equal one, while if my_rank equals the number of processors minus one only the left most RIJ columns are transferred to my_rank-1. The following source works for 2 processors but mpi_scatter (I assume there is an optimized wrapper around mpi_send/recv?) targets all processors. I tried mpi_send+mpi_recv and mpi_sendrecv for nprocs>2 and it hangs up. The domain is broken up only in the X direction so the inner domains need to send data to the adjacent domains. The dimensions of the domains are indexed as slast(is:ie,js:je) while the padded arrays are (paddedSright/left(js:je,0:(RIJ-1)). This is for travel between domains in a pandemic model, right now the Berlin wall is holding up. My domains are typically 10000x5000 XY points and RIJ is 25 (25km average commuting distance). The attached code is general so any size array slast can be passed to it. I can build a quick wrpapper if that is needed, all the variables are in a massive module (virus_initialization) so I won't attach that. As is my usual practice, anyone who helps me solve this will be included on subsequent publications.

Thanks for your time,
Joe

```
#ifdef USEMPI
    USE mpi
    USE VIRUS_INITIALIZATION, only:slast,ilast,rlast,paddedSleft,paddedSright,paddedIleft,paddedIright,&
        paddedRleft,paddedRright,is,ie,js,je,my_rank,nprocs,i,rij,debug,ierr
    use mystuff
    implicit none
    real(8), allocatable::tmpcolumn(:)
    integer(4) ids,idr

    if(my_rank<1)then
    ! first send right Rij column of my_rank to left pad array of my_rank+1
        allocate(tmpcolumn(js:je))
        do i=0,rij-1
            ids=my_rank
            idr=my_rank+1
            !send my_rank=0 S(susceptible) column to my_rank=0 padded array left
            tmpcolumn(js:je)=slast(ie-i,js:je)
            if(debug>=30)write(6,*)'Sending S to Lpad ',my_rank,i,' BLOCK 1R ',maxval(tmpcolumn)
            call MPI_Scatter(tmpcolumn,je,mpi_double,paddedSleft(js,i),je,mpi_double,ids,mpi_comm_world,ierr)
            IF (IERR.NE.MPI_SUCCESS) THEN
                PRINT*, "ERROR: MPI_SCATTER not successful."
                STOP
            ENDIF
            tmpcolumn(js:je)=ilast(ie-i,js:je)
            if(debug>=30)write(6,*)'Sending S to Lpad ',my_rank,i,' BLOCK 1R ',maxval(tmpcolumn)
            call MPI_Scatter(tmpcolumn,je,mpi_double,paddedIleft(js,i),je,mpi_double,ids,mpi_comm_world,ierr)
            IF (IERR.NE.MPI_SUCCESS) THEN
                PRINT*, "ERROR: MPI_SCATTER not successful."
                STOP
            ENDIF
            tmpcolumn(js:je)=rlast(ie-i,js:je)
            if(debug>=30)write(6,*)'Sending S to Lpad ',my_rank,i,' BLOCK 1R ',maxval(tmpcolumn)
            call MPI_Scatter(tmpcolumn,je,mpi_double,paddedRleft(js,i),je,mpi_double,ids,mpi_comm_world,ierr)
            IF (IERR.NE.MPI_SUCCESS) THEN
                PRINT*, "ERROR: MPI_SCATTER not successful."
                STOP
            ENDIF
        enddo
        if(debug>=30)write(6,*)'Sent SIR to Lpad ',my_rank,i,nprocs,maxval(tmpcolumn)
        deallocate(tmpcolumn)
    endif
    call mpi_barrier(mpi_comm_world,ierr)
    if(my_rank>=nprocs-1)then
    ! send left Rij column of my_rank to left pad array of my_rank-1
        allocate(tmpcolumn(js:je))
        do i=0,rij-1
            ids=my_rank
            idr=my_rank-1
            tmpcolumn(js:je)=slast(is+i,js:je)
            if(debug>=30)write(6,*)'Sending S to Rpad ',my_rank,i,' BLOCK 1L ',maxval(tmpcolumn)
            call MPI_Scatter(tmpcolumn,je,mpi_double,paddedSright(js,i),je,mpi_double,ids,mpi_comm_world,ierr)
            IF (IERR.NE.MPI_SUCCESS) THEN
                PRINT*, "ERROR: MPI_SCATTER not successful."
                STOP
            ENDIF
            tmpcolumn(js:je)=ilast(is+i,js:je)
            if(debug>=30)write(6,*)'Sending S to Rpad ',my_rank,i,' BLOCK 1L ',maxval(tmpcolumn)
            call MPI_Scatter(tmpcolumn,je,mpi_double,paddedIright(js,i),je,mpi_double,ids,mpi_comm_world,ierr)
            IF (IERR.NE.MPI_SUCCESS) THEN
                PRINT*, "ERROR: MPI_SCATTER not successful."
                STOP
            ENDIF
            tmpcolumn(js:je)=rlast(is+i,js:je)
            if(debug>=30)write(6,*)'Sending S to Rpad ',my_rank,i,' BLOCK 1L ',maxval(tmpcolumn)
            call MPI_Scatter(tmpcolumn,je,mpi_double,paddedRright(js,i),je,mpi_double,ids,mpi_comm_world,ierr)
            IF (IERR.NE.MPI_SUCCESS) THEN
                PRINT*, "ERROR: MPI_SCATTER not successful."
                STOP
            ENDIF
        enddo
        if(debug>=30)write(6,*)'Sent SIR to Rpad ',my_rank,i,nprocs,maxval(tmpcolumn)
    deallocate(tmpcolumn)
    endif
    if(debug>=30)write(6,*)'Finished padding',my_rank
    call mpi_barrier(mpi_comm_world,ierr)
    IF (IERR.NE.MPI_SUCCESS) THEN
        PRINT*, "ERROR: MPI_SENDRECV not successful."
        STOP
    ENDIF
#endif
    end subroutine virus_BCpad
```

Following Victor's comment I went back to MPI_SENDRECV and now the S/R hangs

````
#ifdef USEMPI
    USE mpi
    USE VIRUS_INITIALIZATION, only:slast,ilast,rlast,paddedSleft,paddedSright,paddedIleft,paddedIright,&
        paddedRleft,paddedRright,is,ie,js,je,my_rank,nprocs,i,rij,debug,ierr
    use mystuff
    implicit none
    real(8), allocatable::tmpcolumn(:)
    integer(4) ids,idrL,idrR,rtag,ltag,stag
    write(6,*)'Transferring BC data'
    allocate(tmpcolumn(js:je))
    ! source rank
    ids=my_rank
    ! desination rank left
    idrL=my_rank-1
    ! desination rank right
    idrR=my_rank+1
    rtag=idrR
    ltag=idrL
    stag=ids
    do i=1,rij-1
        ! if bad rank skip
        if(idrL<0)goto 1
        tmpcolumn(js:je)=slast(is+i,js:je)
        if(debug>=0)write(6,*)'Sending S to Lpad ',my_rank,i,' BLOCK 1L ',maxval(tmpcolumn)
        call MPI_SendRecv(tmpcolumn(:),je,mpi_double,idrL,stag,paddedSleft(:,i),je,mpi_double,ids,rtag,mpi_comm_world,ierr)
        IF (IERR.NE.MPI_SUCCESS) THEN
            PRINT*, "ERROR: MPI_SENDRECV not successful."
            STOP
        ENDIF
1       continue
        ! if bad rank skip
        if(ids>=(nprocs-1))goto 2
        tmpcolumn(js:je)=slast(ie-i,js:je)
        if(debug>=0)write(6,*)'Sending S to Rpad ',my_rank,i,' BLOCK 1R ',maxval(tmpcolumn)
        call MPI_SendRecv(tmpcolumn(:),je,mpi_double,idrR,stag,paddedSright(:,i),je,mpi_double,ids,ltag,mpi_comm_world,ierr)
        IF (IERR.NE.MPI_SUCCESS) THEN
            PRINT*, "ERROR: MPI_SENDRECV not successful."
            STOP
        ENDIF
2       continue
    enddo
    if(debug>=30)write(6,*)'Finished padding',my_rank
    deallocate(tmpcolumn)
    call mpi_barrier(mpi_comm_world,ierr)
    IF (IERR.NE.MPI_SUCCESS) THEN
        PRINT*, "ERROR: MPI_SENDRECV not successful."
        STOP
    ENDIF
#endif
    end subroutine virus_BCpad```

             Transferring BC data
 Transferring BC data
 Sending S to Lpad                      1           1  BLOCK 1L
   2662.64005184174
 Sending S to Rpad                      0           1  BLOCK 1R
   3232.02006292343
````

Comment: You should use `MPI_Send` and `MPI_Recv`, or in this case: `MPI_Sendrecv`. But not `MPI_Scatter` which means "spread the data from one process to all others". Since you have neighbor exchange in one dimension, `MPI_Sendrecv` is indeed the best solution. Rewrite your code and we talk see where you get stuck.

Btw, read up on MPI. Scatter is a "collective" meaning that it involves all processes. Since you do it inside a conditional it will hang because some processes are skipping it.

Comment: Thanks, I will go back to MPI_sendrecv. As a scientist trying to code MPI can be frustrating.